# An analytic function satisfies $f(1/z)=f(z) $, if $f$ is real on $\{|z|=1\}$, then the coefficients of expansion are real.

Tags: complex-analysis

An analytic function satisfies $f(1/z)=f(z),\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\} $, if $f$ has real values on $\{|z|=1\}$, then the coefficients of the Laurent expansion are all real and.

Here is my try, $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} \alpha_n z^n=f(\frac{1}{z})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} \alpha_nz^{-n}$, so $\alpha_n=\alpha_{-n},\forall n\geq 1.$

On $|z|=1, f(z)$ is real, so $\alpha_0=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta}d\zeta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta}} \cdot e^{i\theta}d\theta\in \mathbb{R}$.

When $n\geq 1$,
$\alpha_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}d\zeta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta {(n+1)}}} \cdot e^{i\theta}d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta n}}d\theta$

$\bar{\alpha_n}=\overline{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta n}}d\theta}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{(\frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta n}})}d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{e^{-i\theta n}}d\theta=\alpha_{-n-1}$

Actually the answer said that $\bar{\alpha_n}=\alpha_{-n}$. I don't know what is wrong in the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach which is quite similar, but not completely identical, to that of Adam Hughes:  consider $z$ such that $\vert z \vert = 1$; we may write $z = e^{i \theta}$ for such $z$.  Then we have $\bar z = z^{-1} = e^{-i \theta}$.  Expanding $f(z) = f(z^{-1})$ in terms of $e^{i \theta}$ on the circle $\vert z \vert = 1$ yields

$f(z) = f(e^{i \theta}) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} a_n e^{in\theta} \tag{1}$

and

$f(z^{-1}) = f(e^{-i \theta}) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} a_n e^{-in\theta}; \tag{2}$

using $f(z) = f(z^{-1})$ we obtain

$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} a_n e^{in\theta} = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} a_n e^{-in\theta}, \tag{3}$

from which it follows that $a_m = a_{-m}$ for all $m \in \Bbb Z$, as has been observed by our OP user159895.  Or, to make a somewhat more formal argument, we note that, since $f(z)$ is analytic on $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$, it is continuous on $T = \{z \in \Bbb C \mid \vert z \vert = 1 \}$, hence $f(e^{i\theta}) \in L^2(T)$, and since the functions $e^{in\theta}$, $-\infty < n < \infty$, constitute an orthonormal basis for $L^2(T)$ with respect to the usual inner product

$\langle \omega, \sigma \rangle = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \bar \omega(\theta) \sigma(\theta) d\theta, \tag{4}$

we may simply compute, from (3)

$a_m = \langle e^{im\theta}, \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} a_n e^{in\theta}\rangle = \langle e^{im\theta}, \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} a_n e^{-in\theta} \rangle = a_{-m}; \tag{5}$

likewise, exploiting the hypothesis that $f(z)$ is real on $T$, so that $f(z) = \overline {f(z)}$ there, we find that

$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} a_n e^{in\theta} = \overline{\sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} a_n e^{in\theta}} = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} \bar a_n e^{-in\theta}; \tag{6}$

if we now take the $L^2$ inner product of (6) with $e^{-im\theta}$ we see that

$\bar a_m = a_{-m}, \tag{7}$

which combined with our previous result

$a_m = a_{-m} \tag{8}$

yields

$\bar a_m = a_m, \tag{9}$

the desired conclusion.  ***QED***

***Note:***  The preceding answer assumes my readers are familiar with the basic facts of Fourier analysis on the unit circle $T$, such as $\langle e^{im\theta}, e^{in\theta} \rangle = \delta_{mn}$ and $c_m = \langle e^{im\theta}, \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} c_n e^{in\theta} \rangle$ for $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} c_n e^{in\theta} \in L^2(T)$.  The former is easy to see by direct integration:

$\langle e^{im\theta}, e^{in\theta} \rangle = (1/2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-im\theta}e^{in\theta}d\theta = (1/2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n - m)\theta}d\theta$
$= (1/2\pi)(i(n - m))^{-1}(e^{i(n - m)2\pi} - e^{i(n - m)(0)}) = 0 \tag{10}$

if $m \ne n$ and

$\langle e^{n\theta}, e^{in\theta} \rangle = (1/2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n - n)\theta}d\theta = (1/2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi}1 d\theta = (2\pi/2\pi) = 1. \tag{11}$

The formula

$c_m = \langle e^{im\theta}, \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n = \infty} c_n e^{in\theta} \rangle \tag{12}$

follows from (10) and (11) *via* term-by-term integration.  But these are commonly known tricks of the trade, and most likely anyone reading this post has seen them already.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

The expression you compute for $\overline{a_n}$ looks much more like the expression you computed for $a_{-n}$ thanlike the one you computed for $a_{-n-1}$.

Comment: Yes, i mixed up the $\int_{|\zeta|=1} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{(n+1)}} d\zeta$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f( e^{i\theta})}{ e^{i\theta n}} d\theta$